# Data cache on filesystem, C#

Tags: c#, database, outlook, synchronization

In a software (client-server arch.) I would like to create a cache in local filesystem for some data received over network. (they are marked as DataContract and Serializable). The data can be modified by other users so must be syncronized.

In a few words: I need something like Outlook's *.ost files for Exchange.

What is the best practice to achieve this, or any good solution?

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018859/what-would-you-recommend-for-this-project/. The main difference - you have many users to change data storage. Do they modify data concurently? Can you give some details on how cache must act, when invalidates and how shared? What exact you mean by "syncronized".

Comment: The cache must act the same as outlook does with exchange. Users can create and modify tasks (each type of task has a workflow, like in all issue trackers), documents (invoice, contract...etc), and other things.

Answer (score 1):

My initial thought is to use [SQL Server CE](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx), it's free, file based, fast and secure and uses SQL syntax and tooling.

You would need to define a data schema to store your objects and code storage and retrieval, but you are going to have to do this whatever solution you choose.

Comment: sounds great, and can I synchronize them via custom methods? we have custom protocol (sg like a two-way WCF).

Comment: The added benefit of using SQL Server CE is that you do not need to code for file handling... Just database transaction calls